# Saving a created .msg file as readonly

Tags: c#, office-interop

Hi I had a requirement wherein I convert dxl to .msg file. Since there is no out of the box .NET way to do so, I parsed the xml, got the required fields out, created a .msg file using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook. But when I open the file it looks like a draft mail, ready to be sent. But I would want the file to open as an inbox mail or a sent mail, wherein the fields are 'Not Editable' meaning should be readonly.
My code:

```
mailitem.To = "reciever@recieve.com";
mailitem.SentOnBehalfOfName = "sender@send.com";
mailitem.Subject = "Test for MSG";
mailitem.Body = "Sample Body";
mailitem.SaveAs(temppath + ".msg", OlSaveAsType.olMSG);
```

There is something called SaveSentMessageFolder in mailItem, couldn't figure out how to do so.
Thanks

Comment: Instead of saving the message why don't you send it?

Comment: I don't have the requirement to send just to save them in .msg format, and they are not supposed to be in writable format. So any idea?

Comment: Use the FileInfo class, assign the Attributes property.

Comment: @Hans -  After saving, got the file in FileInfo, and made readonly prop true, but the file is still editable. Didn't help :(

Comment: Sure, but you can't save the changes back.  So nobody can observe the changes you made.

Comment: @Hans - you know how an inbox mail or a sent mail for that matter looks like right, wherein the From, To, Subject and Body are readonly, I want that. But in my case all these are editable.